# Как получить значение свойства объекта другого класса?

Tags: python

Сделал по Доусону пример игры “Паника в пиццерии”.

Пытаюсь теперь немного усложнить игру, изменив скорость падения пиццы при достижении score определенного значения. Получается, что мне нужно из объекта класса `Pizza` получить доступ к аттрибуту объекта класса `Pan`, но никак не получается, выдает ошибку `NameError: name 'the_pan' is not defined`

Пробовал сделать с помощью `@property` и `@setter`, чтобы не забирать из класса `Pizza` атрибут класса `Pan`, а передавать из класса `Pan` значение атрибута в класс `Pizza`, но ошибка одна и та же.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
#Игрок должен падающую пиццу пока она не достигла земли
from livewires import games, color
import random
games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)
class Pan(games.Sprite):
    """Сковорода в которую игрок может ловить падающую пиццу"""
    image = games.load_image("img/pan.bmp")
    def __init__(self):
        """Инициализирует объект pan и создает объект Text для отображения счета"""
        super(Pan, self).__init__(image = Pan.image,
            x = games.mouse.x,
            bottom = games.screen.height)
        self.score = games.Text(value = 0, 
            size = 25, 
            color = color.black,
            top = 5,
            right = games.screen.width -10)
        games.screen.add(self.score)
    def update(self):
        """Передвигает объект по горизонтали в точку с абсциссой, как у указателя мыши"""
        self.x = games.mouse.x
        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0
        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.right = games.screen.width
        self.check_catch()
    def check_catch(self):
        """Проверяет поймал ли игрок падающую пиццу"""
        for pizza in self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.score.value += 10
            self.score.right = games.screen.width - 10
            pizza.handle_caught()
class Pizza(games.Sprite):
    """Круги пиццы падающие на землю"""
    image = games.load_image("img/pizza.bmp")
    speed = 1
    def __init__(self, x, y = 90):
        """Инициализирует объект Pizza"""
        super(Pizza, self).__init__(image = Pizza.image,
            x = x, y = y,
            dy = Pizza.speed)
    def update(self):
        """Проверяет не коснулась ли нижняя кромка пиццы нижнего кря экрана"""
        if self.bottom > games.screen.height:
            self.end_game()
            self.destroy()
    def handle_caught(self):
        """Разрушает объект пойманный игроком"""
        self.destroy()
    def end_game(self):
        """Завершает игру"""
        end_message = games.Message(value = "Game Over",
            size = 90,
            color = color.red,
            x = games.screen.width/2,
            y = games.screen.height/2,
            lifetime =  5 * games.screen.fps,
            after_death = games.screen.quit())
        games.screen.add(end_message)
class Chef(games.Sprite):
    """Кулинар который двигаясь влево-вправо разбрасывает пиццу"""
    image = games.load_image("img/chef.bmp")
    def __init__(self, y = 55, speed = 2, odds_change = 200):
        """Инициализирует объект Chef"""
        super(Chef, self).__init__(image = Chef.image,
            x = games.screen.width/2,
            y = y,
            dx = speed)
        self.odds_change = odds_change
        self.time_til_drop = 0
    def update(self):
        """Определяет надо ли сменить направление"""
        if self.left < 0 or self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        elif random.randrange(self.odds_change) == 0:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        self.check_drop()
    def check_drop(self):
        """Уменьшает интервал ожидания на единицу или сбрасывает очередную пиццу и уменьшает интервал"""
        if self.time_til_drop > 0:
            self.time_til_drop -= 1
        else:
            new_pizza = Pizza(x = self.x)
            games.screen.add(new_pizza)
            #Вне зависимости от скорости падения пиццы, зазор между падающими кругами принимается равным 30% каждого из них по высоте
            self.time_til_drop = int(new_pizza.height * 1.3 / Pizza.speed) + 1
def main():
    """Собственно игровой процесс"""
    wall_image = games.load_image("img/wall.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = wall_image
    the_pan = Pan()
    games.screen.add(the_pan)
    the_chef = Chef()
    games.screen.add(the_chef)
    games.mouse.is_visible = False
    games.screen.event_grab = True
    games.screen.mainloop()
main()
```

Выходит, что объект не существует в тот момент, когда я пытаюсь получить значение. Почему, если он создается в первую очередь?

Comment: Не вижу, чтобы в коде вообще `the_pan` использовалась... Или вы немодифицированный исходник показываете? Покажите тот код, где собственно ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде `the_pan` -- это всего лишь локальная переменная функции `main`, она не является полем класса `Pan`.

Возможно, вам стоит создать класс, который бы управлял существующими в сцене сущностями.

Comment: Спасибо. Вынес содержимое функции main() наружу, так всё работает.

Comment: Пробую засунуть сожержимое этой функции как есть в новый класс, и опять получаю ту же ошибку NameError: name 'the_pan' is not defined, по той же причине. Как это правильно делается? 
Конкретно в этой задаче конечно нет необходимости пихать эти несколько строчек в фунцию или класс, но все же очень хочу знать как это делается.

Comment: Объфявил the_pan глобальной переменной. Так работает. Не знаю насколько это правильно, вроде как считается неправильным использовать глобальные переменные.